# Center map on window resize with Google Maps Engine

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-engine

Trying to put map on my web page from Google's Map Engine service:

```
<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zcYcL12izhP0.kBlDVAO1nRr8" width="100%" height="480"></iframe>
```

How to center map on window resize? -  [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/dVR7V/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to access the document inside the iframe, because it's located on a different domain. Therefore it's not  possible to use any API-method to manipulate the map from the parent window.

The only option I see so far is to reload the iframe when the size of the parent window changes(what also changes the size of the iframe)

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/zSHBe/

Comment: This method works, but it causing additional reload of map, what takes more time. Thanks!