# Center Google map generated with Maps Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I'm trying to implement the solution found at [Center map on window resize with Google Maps Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046038/center-map-on-window-resize-with-google-maps-engine) in a Drupal site.  The page is here http://dspdesignworks.com/projects/neversummernordic/page/location

I've added the Iframe code to a block and added the JS to the head section however, I get a blank page.

JS code added to head:

```
    window.onresize=function(){
    var frame=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    frame.setAttribute('src','https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zFhzxVukKcLo.kPyCeTJuW86s'+new Date().getTime())
    }
```

Iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zFhzxVukKcLo.kPyCeTJuW86s" height="480" width="1950"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to just walk away and then try again.  I'm using a module for Drupal called "Add to Head" and apparently, it automatically adds the opening and closing "script" tags.  When I removed them from the code, the map showed centered as it should.